# How to confirm sector error on a video DVD

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ubuntu-10.10, dvd

If a DVD skips at around 21:00 mark is there anyway to relate that to kernel messages?
I would like to know if the DVD format is standard enough that I could compare the time the movie skips with the sectors shown below? Or do I just have a crappy DVD player?

```
[19841.316576] UDF-fs INFO UDF: Mounting volume 'INGLOURIOUS_BASTERDS', timestamp 2009/11/03 20:34 (1f10)
[19876.642717] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[19876.642725] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[19876.642732] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[19876.642743] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 04 ec 00 00 40 00
[19876.642758] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 5040
[19876.642764] quiet_error: 15 callbacks suppressed
[19876.642768] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1260
[19876.642772] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1261
[19876.642782] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1262
[19876.642789] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1263
[19876.642796] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1264
[19876.642803] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1265
[19876.642808] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1266
[19876.642812] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1267
[19876.642816] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1268
[19876.642820] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1269
[19876.661744] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[19876.661750] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[19876.661757] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[19876.661766] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 05 2c 00 00 20 00
[19876.661780] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 5296
[19876.747517] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[19876.747525] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[19876.747532] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[19876.747543] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 05 04 00 00 02 00
[19876.747557] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 5136
[19945.912754] lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
```

Comment: Doesn't quite answer the question, but you could try ripping the disc with your program of choice, then inspect the program's log - you'll likely get read errors that will probably identify the sector.